# how to separate buttons and paragraphs in div within javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I'm doing this thing, where i have input(the number of people) and when user inputted its creating a new paragraphs and buttons for each person, but when I try to add something on button onclick for each person(for example for first person, user wants to input the name), it just wents to the first button but for 2nd for instance it doesnt working, it just works fine for first person but for others it doesnt perform, please help me here is my js:

```
      // creating the array for how many people come
      const peopleArray = [];

      function addPeople() {
        /* reading the document from button input and converting
        it to the number
        */
        const inputForPeopleElement = document.querySelector('.howManyPeople');
        const people = Number(inputForPeopleElement.value);

        // adding the number of people to the array
        for (let i = 1; i <= people; i++) {
          peopleArray.push(i);
        }

        // doing the value 0/nothing when user gonna inputs new people 
        console.log(peopleArray);
        inputForPeopleElement.value = '';

        howManyHours();  // calling the function for knowing and creating new divs for people
      }

      /* reading the button by the id and if user clicks
      it does two actions  
      */

      let acceptButton = document.getElementById('js-accept');
      acceptButton.addEventListener('click', addPeople);
      acceptButton.addEventListener('click', acceptedClickForPeople);

      /*
      creating function for knowing if user clicks innit 
      the button changes 
      */
      function acceptedClickForPeople() {
        const changeAcceptanceElement = document.querySelector('.accept');
        if (changeAcceptanceElement.innerText === 'Принять') {
          changeAcceptanceElement.innerText = 'Принято';
        }
        // Add a setTimeout function to revert the button text after a delay
        setTimeout(function () {
          changeAcceptanceElement.innerText = 'Принять';
        }, 1000); // Change the delay value (in milliseconds) as needed
      }

      let buttonForName = document.getElementById('js-inputForName');

      function acceptedClickForName() {
        const changedButtonForName = document.querySelector('.buttonChange');
        if (changedButtonForName.innerText === 'Сохранить') {
          changedButtonForName.innerText = 'Сохранено';
          setTimeout(function () {
            changedButtonForName.innerText = 'Сохранить';
          }, 1000); // Change the delay value (in milliseconds) as needed
        }
      }
      function showTheName() {
        const changedButtonForName = document.querySelector('.inputForName');
        const htmlForName = `<p>${changedButtonForName.value}</p>`
        document.querySelector('.showName').innerHTML = htmlForName;
        console.log(htmlForName);
      }

      let personOneOrMany = 0;

      let htmlForPersons = '';

      // a new function for creating a new div for each person
      function howManyHours() {

        let howManyHoursHtml = ''; // for storing the result 
        for (let i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++) {
          personOneOrMany++;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++) {

          const hoursVariable = peopleArray[i]; // hoursVariable to save the indexes 

          // creating a paragraph for each personz

          // combining all of the html together
          const html = `<p> ${i + 1} человек </p>
                <div id = "timer" class = "timer">
                <input placeholder = "Имя" class = "inputForName">
                <button class = "buttonChange" id = "js-buttonChange" onclick = "
                acceptedClickForName();
                showTheName();
                "> Сохранить </button>
                <div>
                <p class = "showName"> </p>
                </div>
                <input placeholder = "Минуты">
                <button class = "inputForTimer" id = "js-inputForName"> Сохранить </button>
                </div>`;
          howManyHoursHtml += html;
        }

        document.querySelector('.js-howManyHours').innerHTML = howManyHoursHtml; // getting the js code to the html and showing on the page

        console.log(howManyHoursHtml);

        howManyHoursHtml = '';

        personOneOrMany = 0;
      }
```

tried with my best as I can, thinking it's array problem but not sure exactly

Answer (score 0):

just need to create new addEventListeners for each button or for each input that I wanted to use, and with it getting the querySelectorAll and with forEach() function working on it, with this I can get the each paragraph or button that I need to work on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).